ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED Intent received for SD Card but not for USB Drive
In my Android Application, I have to detect when an external storage device is attached or removed (SD Card or USB Drive) so that I can perform some action when this happens
I implemented a broadcast receiver for ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED and ACTION_MEDIA_UNMOUNTED intents.
If I insert or remove an SD card, it works but it is not working in the case of USB drive. What can be the reason ?
In onReceive of MyBroadcastReceiver, I am just logging the intent action for now.
It looks like this :
`
override
fun onReceive(p0: Context?, p1: Intent?)
{
Log.d ("Test", "Inside onReceive")
Log.d ("Test", "${p1?.action}")
}
`
`
    var receiver = MyBroadcastReceiver()
    var filter   = IntentFilter ()

    filter.addAction("android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED")
    filter.addAction("android.intent.action.MEDIA_EJECT")
    filter.addAction("android.intent.action.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED")

    filter.addDataScheme("file")   // Doesn't work without this data scheme

    registerReceiver (receiver, filter);

`
I have also tried registering the Broadcast listener in the Manifest file instead of doing it programmatically but the results were same. It works for SD Card and not for USB Storage
